# how to design a template without using margins, padding, position for a outlook email

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have to design a template for microsoft outlook email which requires me to place a dynamic image and text from server on an existing static background image. I tried designing it using div's as well as table and also gave inline css and (!important) for the html. I could not find support for tags such as margins, float,positions and my layout always breaks. I found that outlook email does not support those css attributes. Please suggest me a way to design the template without layout breaks.

[this is how my template should look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRSVr.png)

http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/
Above link

I tried it in two different ways for aligning them:

```
using div:
    <div align="left"><img style="padding: 5px; border: 3px solid white; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 171px; height: 143px;" src="staticimage.png " alt=" ">
                            <h4 style=" font-family: serif; color: rgb(255, 252, 252);">#Some Text#</h4></div>
                        <h3 style="font-family: -webkit-body !important;font-style: italic;color: #147C6C; margin-top:-55px">Text</h3>
                        <img style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, arial !important;
                                        width: 731px;height: 500px; margin-top:-150px;margin-left:25px" src="dynamicimage.png">

     using table:
 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, arial !important;width: 731px;height: 500px;" src="staticimage.jpg">
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <span style="margin-left: -1458px;">
                            <img style=" padding: 5px; border: 3px solid white; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 171px; height: 143px;" src="dynamicimage.png " alt=" ">
                            <span><h4 style=" font-family: serif; color: rgb(255, 252, 252);margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; ">#some text#</h4></span>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <span style="margin-left: -1253px;">
                            <img style="width: 350px;height: 225px;margin-top: 44px; " src="dynamictext.png " alt=" ">
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <h2 style="margin: -5px 0px -55px -877px;font-family: -webkit-body !important;font-style: italic;color: #147C6C; ">
                            <strong>Some text</strong>
                            </h2>
                        <h3 style="margin:54px 0px -5px -864px;font-family: -webkit-body !important;font-style: italic;color: #147C6C; ">Employee name</h3>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Please post some code, to show us what have you tried so far. SO is not a coding service.

Comment: hi Please use for it table structure html. it is compatible for all mail box.

Comment: @Kiran Khatri -table background url:(image) also did not work.Is there any other way to add an image as table background ?  Link above shows the outlook supported css properties.

Answer (score 0):

Tables usually work with outlook emails but if they are not, if you're trying to get 40px margin, for instance, add a 40px transparent image on the location.

Comment: thank you.  I need one image to be positioned on another image. using transparent image gives me margin.please suggest me a way to place one image on another.